# Codeception AcceptanceTester::loadSessionSnapshot is undefined

Tags: codeception

I am trying to test a project but unable to check the login page due to this error:

`[RuntimeException] Call to undefined method AcceptanceTester::loadSessionSnapshot`

This is my code:

```
<?php 
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('Login');
$I->amOnPage('/');
if($I->loadSessionSnapshot('loggedin')) exit();
$I->dontSee('NotFound');
//$I->dontSee('Error');
$csrf = $I->grabCookie('_token');
$I->submitForm('.form',array('login'=>array(
        'username'=>'username',
        'password'=>'*******'
    )
));
$I->saveSessionSnapshot('loggedin');
$I->see('username');
```

And my config is like this

```
# Codeception Test Suite Configuration
#
# Suite for acceptance tests.
# Perform tests in browser using the WebDriver or PhpBrowser.
# If you need both WebDriver and PHPBrowser tests - create a separate suite.

class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: http://myweb.com
        - \Helper\Acceptance
```

I generated this using the commandline command

```
codecept.bat generate:cept acceptance loginTest
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such method in [PhpBrowser](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/PhpBrowser) module,
loadSessionSnapshot method is only provided by 
[WebDriver](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#loadSessionSnapshot).

Don't use exit() in tests, it kills Codeception too.
Use skip method instead.

```
if($I->loadSessionSnapshot('loggedin')) {
    $scenario->skip('Already logged in');
}
```

Comment: the PhpBrowser might get the support soon:
https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/pull/3321#issuecomment-231206894